# Unconstrained Optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization

```
function f = objfun(x)
f = exp(x(1)) * (4*x(1)^2 + 2*x(2)^2 + 4*x(1)*x(2) + 2*x(2) + 1);
x0=[-1,1];
options = optimoptions(@fminunc,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fminunc(@objfun,x0,options);
x,fval,exitflag,output
end
```

Can you please help me in running the code?

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? If yes, then where were you got stuck and had to post the question ?

Comment: I got stuck in Error "Input Argument x is undefined "

Comment: Thnx,on defining fiminunc outside the objfun , I get the error in Line [x,fval,exitflag,output] = fminunc(@objfun,x0,options);
,This statement is not inside any function.

Comment: Apply the changes that I have written and run the code as a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `f` to a function handle as

```
fun = @(x) exp(x(1)) * (4*x(1)^2 + 2*x(2)^2 + 4*x(1)*x(2) + 2*x(2) + 1);
```

then call `fminunc` with

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fminunc(fun,x0,options);
```

As a side note, don't *ever* call `fminunc` from within the objective function.

Comment: After correction ,  I find this error  "This statement is not inside any function."

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Try to run it from the workspace (same as running as a script) after a clear all.

Comment: Ok maybe I got it. You can't define a function inside a script, so if you want to keep the objective function as a separate function you must declare it as a _nested_ function.